# Set property to current width of element with CSS?

Tags: css

I'm looking for some syntax like this:

```
.centered{
    left: calc(50% - current-width/2)
}
```

Basically, a way to reference the `current-width` of the target element so that I can have a flexible-width item centered.  Does this exist?

Comment: `left: 50%; transform: translateX(-50%);` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform-function/translateX

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One answer is to move it left and then translate it:

```
.centered {
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%);
}
```

But a better way is to use Flexbox on the parent element:

```
.centeredParent {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
}
```